# Arduino Bluetooth starting remote phone call

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, phone-call

I would like to know if it's possible with an Arduino and a Bluetooth module to start a phone call remotely to a specific phone number ? And if yes how ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To speculate on this a little, it would make sense to use a Bluetooth profile that is already supported on the phone so that you do not have to write a custom application for the phone. The [Hands-Free Profile (HFP)](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview/) specification details how to send a phone number to the phone to make a call. Look at section:

4.18 Place a Call with the Phone Number Supplied by the HF

Quick search for "Bluetooth HFP Arduino" gave some results so it seems like there are breakout boards with Arduino library support. e.g.

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/understanding-the-bc127-bluetooth-module/all

Disclaimer: I have not actually done this but it is how I would go about it.

Comment: Thank for the awnser, I will try it on Monday